# Django - Comment form in an existing template. How to define it in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have 4 models: Post, Comment, Blogger and User.

I have an post_description template, in below of that, I have placed a comment form.

But how to define it in views? My problem is - to get its username, like the user who is logged in will be stored as "posted_by" and in which blog post he post will be stored as "topic" of the blog.

How to store these information, so they get automatically added?

Form that i has described in post_desc.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="comment" style="width: 800px; height: 145px;">
    <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
  </form>
{% else %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> to comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

Current view of that post_desc:

```
def post_desc(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'post_desc.html', {'post': post})
```

Comment: So this descripion template, what it does is, enable logged in users to comment on the post, is that it?

Comment: It prints post topic, time, and description. I didn't mentionedit here, i just mentioned here only form.

Comment: you can access logged in user from request. `request.user`

Comment: How is the Topic related to the Post?

Comment: @shourav and post topic with request.post_topic?

Answer (score 1):

Now the user can be accessed as follows in the views:

```
user = request.user
```

And about the Topic, maybe you could add a hidden input in your form to get blog id , as you are already passing the post in the form template. :

```
 <form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="comment" style="width: 800px; height: 145px;">
<input type="hidden" name="topic" value="{{ post.id }}">
<button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
```

And when posted in the view you can get blog by:

```
post_id = request.POST.get('topic')
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
```

And then finally proceeding with your actual flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is basic model form setup.

I am hoping there is a blog entry and comments associated with it and you want a commenting functionality on each post.

This is rough quick answer. 
Your models.py looks like this:

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    comment = models.TextField()
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You setup a model form in your forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comments

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comment']
```

You setup a model form post view.

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def post_comments_controller(request, identifier):
    from .forms import CommentForm
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comment_obj = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        topic = Blog.objects.get(id=identifier)
        comment_obj.posted_by = request.user
        comment_obj.item = topic
        comment_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse("Done")
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

You setup a entry point in your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^/blog/(?P<identifier>[d]+)/comment$',
                           'views.post_comments_controller', name='post_comment')
)
```

And your finally the html form

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'post_comment' blog.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="comment" style="width: 800px; height: 145px;">
    <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
  </form>
{% else %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> to comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is not tested overall. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) you can use `FormMixin` with `DetailView` like this:

```py
class AuthorInterestForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField()

class AuthorDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Author
    form_class = AuthorInterestForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Here, we would record the user's interest using the message
        # passed in form.cleaned_data['message']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```